# How to inspect Haskell bytecode

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to figure out a bug (a serious performance downgrade).  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out why by going back many different versions of my code.

I am suspecting it could be some modifications to libraries that I've updated, not to mention in the meanwhile I've updated to GHC 7.6 from 7.4 (and if anybody knows if some laziness behavior has changed I would greatly appreciate it!).

I have an older executable of this code that does not have this bug and thus I wonder if there are any tools to tell me the library versions I was linking to from before?  Like if it can figure out the symbols, etc.

Comment: You know that GHC compiles to machine code, not bytecode, right?  Also, 'Haskell' as a language does not define any bytecode.

Comment: Depends on the OS, but on the Linux box, it is ldd (this will work on all executalbes, and it will give you the c libraries linkes against, not the Haskell ones so it might not be what you want).

Comment: you'll probably have to read core but before you try to do that you probably just want to profile your code.

Comment: On linux you can obtain assembly from you executable file using objdump, then you can try to compare them.

Comment: There is no bytecode. The closest equivalent is the Core, which is sometimes read to diagnose performance problems. Ask ghc to `--ddump-simpl` and you get the core.

Comment: GHCi emits bytecode, ghc -e 1+1 -ddump-bcos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC creates executables, which are notoriously hard to understand...  On my Linux box I can view the assembly code by typing in

```
objdump -d <executable filename>
```

but I get back over 100K lines of code from just a simple "[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)" program written in Haskell.

If you happen to have the GHC .hi files, you can get some information about the executable by typing in

```
ghc --show-iface <hi filename>
```

This won't give you the assembly code, but you can get some extra information that may prove useful.

As I mentioned in the comment above, on Linux you can use "ldd" to see what C-system libraries you used in the compile, but that is also probably less than useful.

You can try to use a disassembler, but those are generally written to disassemble to C, not anything higher level and certainly not Haskell.  That being said, GHC compiles to C as an intermediary (at least it used to; has that changed?), so you might be able to learn something.

Personally I often find view system calls in action much more interesting than viewing pure assembly.  On my Linux box, I can view all system calls by running using [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) (use [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) for the network traffic equivalent):

```
strace <program executable>
```

This also will generate a lot of data, so it might only be useful if you know of some specific place where direct real world communication (i.e., changes to a file on the hard disk drive) goes wrong.

In all honesty, you are probably better off just debugging the problem from source, although, depending on the actual problem, some of these techniques may help you pinpoint something.

Most of these tools have Mac and Windows equivalents.

Comment: I just want to add, that by compiling an executable as `-dynamic` and making sure you subtracted the RTS, you will have much less assembly code to deal with.

Comment: No, GHC does not compile to C as an intermediary. In its very early versions, it compiled to Cmm, with is an intermediate representation, but not C. Nowadays (2017), it compiles to machine code directly, or uses LLVM, which seems to become the new standard, since LLVM can compile to a *lot* of architectures, including ARM and WebAssembly.

Comment: Btw, `htop` has `strace`ing and showing a list of open files (including libraries) nicely built in, just one key press away.

Answer (score 0):

Since much has changed in the last 9 years, and apparently this is still the first result a search engine gives on this question (like for me, again), an updated answer is in order:

First of all, yes, while Haskell does not specify a bytecode format, bytecode is also just a kind of machine code, for a virtual machine. So for the rest of the answer I will treat them as the same thing. The “Core“ as well as the LLVM intermediate language, or even WASM could be considered equivalent too.

Secondly, if your old binary is statically linked, then of course, no matter the format your program is in, no symbols will be available to check out. Because that is what linking does. Even with bytecode, and even with just classic static `#include` in simple languages. So your old binary will be no good, no matter what. And given the optimisations compilers do, a classic decompiler will very likely never be able to figure out what optimised bits used to be partially what libraries. Especially with stream fusion and such “magic”.

Third, **you *can* do the things you asked with a modern Haskell program. But** you need to have your binaries compiled with `-dynamic` and `-rdynamic`, So not only the C-calling-convention libraries (e.g. `.so`), and the Haskell libraries, but also the runtime itself is dynamically loaded. That way you end up with a very small binary, consisting of only your actual code, dynamic linking instructions, and the exact data about what libraries and runtime were used to build it. And since the runtime is compiler-dependent, you will know the compiler too. So it would give you everything you need, but only if you compiled it right. (I recommend using such dynamic linking by default in any case as it saves memory.)

The last factor that one might forget, is that even the exact same compiler version might behave vastly differently, depending on what IT was compiled with. (E.g. if somebody put a backdoor in the very first version of GHC, and all GHCs after that were compiled with that first GHC, and nobody ever checked, then that backdoor could still be in the code today, with no traces in any source or libraries whatsoever. … Or for a less extreme case, that version of GHC your old binary was built with might have been compiled with different architecture options, leading to it putting more optimised instructions into the binaries it compiles for unless told to cross-compile.)

Finally, of course, you can profile even compiled binaries, by profiling their system calls. This will give you clues about which part of the code acted differently and how. (E.g. if you notice that your new binary floods the system with some slow system calls where the old one just used a single fast one. A classic OpenGL example would be using fast display lists versus slow direct calls to draw triangles. Or using a different sorting algorithm, or having switched to a different kind of data structure that fits your work load badly and thrashes a lot of memory.)